# The checkbox function can only be used just on the first line in php

Tags: javascript

I have a modal and in this modal, I have a checkbox, The checkbox function can only be used on the first line table.

Code is like this, the checkbox function works but only on the first row of the table, henceforth the modal process doesn't work, I've tried adding

```
<?php echo $data['id_user']; ?>
```

to the ID but it still doesn't work.

```
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="ubah_password">Ubah Password</label>
        <div class="form-group">
            <input type="checkbox" id="ubah_password" name="ubah_password" value="1">
            <label class="prevent-select" for="ubah_password"> Ya, saya ingin mengubah password</label>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="form_password" style="display: none;">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="editPassAdmin">Password Baru</label>
            <input type="password" class="form-control form-control-sm" id="editPassAdmin" name="editPassAdmin" placeholder="Masukkan password baru">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="password_confirm">Konfirmasi Password</label>
            <input type="password" class="form-control form-control-sm" id="password_confirm" name="password_confirm" placeholder="Masukkan kembali password baru">
        </div>
    </div>

    <script>
        var checkbox = document.getElementById("ubah_password");
        var formPassword = document.getElementById("form_password");

        checkbox.addEventListener("change", function() {
            if (this.checked) {
                formPassword.style.display = "block";
            } else {
                formPassword.style.display = "none";
            }
        });
    </script>
```

Comment: There's no table or multiple "rows" -> [mcve]

Comment: How is PHP related to this question?

Comment: If you have more than one checkbox you’ll need to assign more than one event listener.

Answer (score 1):

The [HTML ID attribute is designed to be unique](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/id), so even if you repeat it, you need to select them all, then individually in your JavaScript to load the modal.

Also, the `name` attributes should probably be unique enough for your form PHP code to tell which password you are changing.

For example, you could change the ID attributes to something like:

```
id="ubah_password[<?php echo $data['id_user']; ?>]"
```

Comment: I've already tried it, but it still only works on the first data